# How do I change the selection in BBEdit's Currently Open Document pane with the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, text-editor

When I open more than one document in BBEdit, a Currently Open Documents pane is shown. I can change the selection in the pane (and change the document shown in the editor pane) with the mouse pointer. Can I change the selection in the pane with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the menubar -> View -> Previous Document/Next Document. The shortcut for *Previous Document* seems to be <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and for *Next Document* <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> on an US-keyboard.

On my (german) keyboard I use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> though.

Comment: You're right. It is alt-cmd-[ and alt-cmd-] on my US keyboard. (I changed them to shift-cmd-[ and shift-cmd-] for consistency with apps that use tabs.)