# Change Between Open Documents, SPANISH Keyboard, LibreOffice Chrome

Tags: keyboard, macos, google-chrome, libreoffice

I found this article:

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/09/13/quickly-change-between-open-documents-mac-this-keyboard-shortcut/

According to changing between multiple opened documents in LibreOffice and Chrome.

[image]

But I was testing in **macOS Sierra** with **Spanish** Keyboard and was not Working on **LibreOffice** and **Chrome**.

Here the video of my result testing: https://youtu.be/1oz0OlNmw2E

With this answer:
[How do I change the selection in BBEdit's Currently Open Document pane with the keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218755/how-do-i-change-the-selection-in-bbedits-currently-open-document-pane-with-the)

Is not working.

Where I Can set a new Key combination alternative (different to WITCH)?